# I want to add a server to my domain name

Tags: networking, web

I recently purchased a domain name and I have an old computer I was wondering if there were any how to's or tutorials on how to set up the server and use the domain name I already purchased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just providing with a beautiful link which guides one to set up a safe and secure Web Server.

here it goes--->http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2012/11/how-to-set-up-a-safe-and-secure-web-server/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend installing something like Ubuntu Minimal 14.04 on the old machine, then hooking it up to the internet and installing NGINX. After you have the website working, you can forward ports 80 and 443 and set the DNS of your domain to your IP address.